# failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement' in reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

In the form of a data record, I upload a picture, the image will be uploaded to a server folder and its name will be stored in the database.

in this editing form i get the file name from server and i need to fill `<input type="file">` in this form . using the reactive form in angular6 .

this is my code in ts file :

```
   ngOnInit() {
  this.EditForm=this.fb.group({
  imageName:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
})
this.SetForm(this.dat)
}

  SetForm(dt:data){
   this.EditForm.setValue({imageName:[dt.imageName]});
  }
```

in html :

```
<form [formGroup]="EditForm">
    <input type="file" #file formControlName="imageName">
</form>
```

and this is my code : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcstxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

i not idea for this problem , and i have 3 days have problem , please see my code and change that for solve this problem .

Comment: Just to check, are you able to upload the file in the first place? Or do you only need help in "renaming" the file after upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename your image file with this trick:

On your component.html, you add the event listener to listen to `change`:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #file formControlName="imageName">
```

And on your component.ts, this will create a new file with the updated file name

```
onFileChange(event) {
  //console.log(event.target.files[0].name)
  var blob = event.target.files[0].slice(0, event.target.files[0].size, 'image/png'); 

  const newFile = new File([blob], this.dat.imageName, {type: 'image/png'})
  //console.log(newFile)
}
```

This maintains the original file name on `input`, but you can use `newFile` in your `post`/`put` request to be sent to the backend.

Comment: my problem not to upload file . my problem to set value for edit

Comment: This creates a new file with the name you stated on the stackblitz. You can console.log it and it actually prints the file with the updated name

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, it's possible to set programmatically only an empty string to a file input value to clear the selection. If you set a value to input with type file, you'll get an error like:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': 
This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set 
to the empty string.
```

As a workaround for modern browsers, `DataTransfer` might be used for changing file input value:

HTML (based on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcstxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)):

```
<form [formGroup]="EditForm">
  <input id="my-input" type="file">
</form>

<button (click)="changeFileName()">Change File Name</button>
```

Component:

```
changeFileName() {
  const dataTransfer = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
  dataTransfer.items.add(new File(['my-file'], 'new-file-name'));
  const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById('my-input') as HTMLInputElement

  inputElement.files = dataTransfer.files;
}
```

Comment: yes it show me this error . but how can i solve this error?

Comment: I've created workaround based on your code, using DataTransfer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpwdra?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts , but it'll work only in modern browsers

Answer (score 2):

remove formControlName="image" and replace it with (change)="onChangeImage()"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me;

```js
changeFileName() {
  const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById('my-input') as HTMLInputElement
  inputElement.files = null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For those using ReactJs, remove the value field from the file input control to resolve the issue.

Comment: please add a code snippet as well and add a more brief explanation in an answer.